# Combining multiple histograms in one plot with dataset-specific binning

Tags: plotting

Combining several dataset for a single `Histogram` call, uses same coarse bin size for all, how do I get dataset-specific binning?

```
genDistances[d_] := (
   m = 1000;
   A = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {m, d}]/Sqrt[d];
   removeZeros[l_] := DeleteCases[l, 0.];
   removeZeros@Flatten@UpperTriangularize@DistanceMatrix[A]
   );
Histogram @@ {genDistances /@ {10, 100, 1000}}
```

[image]

Wondering if this is something `bspec` is supposed to help with. Documentation is short on examples. Motivation: illustrates how distances collapse in higher dimensions ([discussion](https://twitter.com/davisidarta/status/1716860964962726249)).

Comment: `Show[MapIndexed[Histogram[#, ChartStyle -> Opacity[.5, ColorData[97][#2[[1]]]]] &]@
  Map[genDistances]@{10, 100, 1000}]`?

Comment: ah, `ColorData[97]` saves the day. I guess I also need PDF scaling `Show[MapIndexed[
   Histogram[#, "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF", 
     ChartStyle -> Opacity[.5, ColorData[97][#2[[1]]]]] &]@
  Map[genDistances]@{10, 100, 1000}]`